# Best way to do a regular expressions substitution

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following code to change the version string inside the `provider "aws"` block. using `re.search()` and `re.sub()`. Is it possible to do it with just `re.sub()`?

```
def process(p, provider, version):
  g = re.search(r'provider\s+"%s"\s+\{[\s\S]*version\s+=\s+"(.*)"[\s\S]*\}' % provider, p).group(1)
  return re.sub(r'%s' % g, '~> ' + version, p)

p = """
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  version = "~> 2.59"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "tes_role"
  }
}
"""

r = process(p, "aws", "2.61")
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you need to use a capturing group and an unambiguous replacement backreference when using `re.sub`, and you need to alter the pattern a bit:

```
def process(p, provider, version):
  return re.sub(r'(provider\s+"{}"\s+{{[\s\S]*?version\s+=\s+"~>\s*)[^"]*'.format(provider),
    r'\g<1>{}'.format(version),
    p)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UxHG0w)

The pattern is

```
(provider\s+"aws"\s+{[\s\S]*?version\s+=\s+"~>\s*)[^"]*
```

And the replacement is `\g<1>2.61`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Apc1Eo/2).

**Details**

- `(provider\s+"aws"\s+{[\s\S]*version\s+=\s+"~>\s*)` - Group 1 (`\g<1>` is the backreference to the group value (**note** you can't use `\1` because the next char is a digit!)):

  - `provider` - a word
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `"aws"` - `"aws"`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `{` - a `{` char (in a format string, it must be doubled)
  - `[\s\S]*` - 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `version` - a word `version`
  - `\s+=\s+` - a `=` char enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
  - `"~>` - a `"~>` substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`